# Linking View Controllers to TableView entries

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios6

I have made a table view, with 19 entries. What I would like is to have each one connected individually to a view controller, since all the view controllers are going to be different.

The code I've used for the tableView is:

```
tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One", @"Two",[...], nil];
```

Is there a way to connect each one of those entries to a seperate view controller?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the UITableViewDelegate methods.
The one you will need to implement for this is:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

see also apple documentation: [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

hope this helps...

Comment: I've been using this code http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/ . How do I connect each row to a seperate view controller?